# Matrix multiplication of $A \in M_{3 \times 2}$ and $B \in M_{2 \times 3}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two matrices $A \in M_{3 \times 2}$, $B \in M_{2 \times 3}$, and 
$AB=$ \begin{bmatrix}8 &2&-2\\2&5&4\\-2&4&5 \end{bmatrix}, find $BA$.

I noticed that $\det{AB}=0$, $\text{rank}{(AB)}=2$ and $AB$ is symmetric. Since it is symmetric, I guessed $AB$ can be factored into the multiplication of the matrix and its conjugate, but this method needed complicated computation. So far, I didn't have any idea. Does anybody have a good idea?

Comment: One solution, found by PARI, is : [2, -2; -1, -2; -2, -1] [2, -1, -2; -2, -2, -1] [9, 0; 0, 9]

Comment: @Peter Thank you. Is there any other solutions? I think $A$, $B$ may not unique, how about the matrix $BA$?

Comment: That is the great question! I have no idea how to prove the uniqueness of BA. In all solutions I found, BA was [ [9,0] [0,9 ] ]

Comment: Furthermore, PARI states that the determinant of AB is always 0 (for any 3x2-matrix A and any 2x3-matrix B). It would be interesting to prove this amazing result.

Comment: @Peter: just add a column of zeros to A and a row of zeros to B. The product is still AB, but now they are 3x3 matrices and the determinant of the product is the product of determinants. And the determinant of a matrix with a column of zeros is zero.

Comment: To me it seems like something is wrong with your computations. $BA$ is a $2 \times 2$-matrix with determinant zero, so the maximal possible rank is $1$, whereas you  have computed $2$.

Comment: @user126154 very good argument!

Comment: For any invertible $2\times 2$ matrix $C$, there is another solution $AC$ and $C^{-1}B$.  That changes $BA$ to $C^{-1}BAC$.  In this case, $BA=9I$, so $C^{-1}BAC=9C^{-1}C=9I$.

Comment: It only remains to prove that every solution is of the form $AC,C^{-1}B$ for some invertible C, if A,B is a special solution, but the approach is promising!

Comment: I can show $BA$ is invertible. Since $\text{rank}(BA) \geq \text{rank}(A(BA)B) = \text{rank}((AB)^2)=2$, and $BA$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $BA$ is invertible. I am not sure if this information is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As can be directly calculated, $\text{trace}(AB)=\text{trace}(BA)$ for any $3\times 2$-matrix $A$ and $2 \times 3$-matrix $B$.
 Furthermore, it can be also directly calculated, that the determinant of BA can be
 calculated as follows :

If $AB$ has the values 
$\begin{bmatrix}
 a &b& c\\ d& e& f\\ g &h &i
\end{bmatrix},$
then $\det(BA)$ is the sum of the determinants of the matrices
$\begin{bmatrix}
 a& b\\ d &e
\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}
 a& c\\ g &i
\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}
 e& f\\ h &i
\end{bmatrix}$.

In our case, this leads to the determinant $81$.

So, we have $\text{trace}(BA) = 18$ and $\det(BA) = 81$.

But this is still not enough to show the uniqueness of $BA$.

Comment: for 2x2 matrices, the trace and the determinat determine the characteristic polynomial $\det(A-xI)=x^2-TrAx+\det A$. Therefore A has two eigenvalues $9$. As we know that a solution is $9I$ then by the above comment of Michael, we know that $9I$ is the unique solution.